# Is getServerSideProps run every request in page or is it run only for http request?

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

Is getServerSideProps run every request in page or is it run only for HTTP requests?

Comment: `getServerSideProps` is run on every request to the page and also on client-side page navigations. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#when-does-getserversideprops-run.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[The official Next.js document on Data Fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) says,

> If you export a function called getServerSideProps (Server-Side Rendering) from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data returned by getServerSideProps.

this means your tsx,jsx pages will pass through `getServerSideProps` and gets re-rendered every time a user visits the page **in production environment**.

## The exception

However, the page does not get re-rendered in these cases:

1. when the page is accessed from **development environment**, it'll be re-rendered every time to ease the development.
2. when the page includes `getStaticProps`, the page will not be re-rendered, unless [a specific cache revalidation strategy](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) is set.

> Is getServerSideProps run every request in page or is it run only for HTTP requests?

## On Next.js API Routes

Not really sure what **http request** means in your question, because it can either mean:

1. http request to page, that is not https request
2. API routes, that is not page request
   because http is just a protocol which can also be applied to page requests.

if you've meant 2, API routes, those of Next.js do not use `getServerSideProps`. It uses [route handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) instead.